# I want to remove one object from my render so that it leaves just a transparent background

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes, cryptomatte

[image: compositing]

I want to remove the pool water from my image, so that there is only a transparent background, so that I can add the pool I rendered in luxcore in photoshop.
Right now, because I could not get it to work, I used the following node setup. Mixing the images right in blender; but I didn't like the color of the luxcore render in that.
Any tipps?

Comment: provide your blend file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a very advanced Blender user so take this for what it's worth... Could you not render the scene without the water (using Cycles, I assume) and then simply take that image and the "pool" from the LuxCore render and merge the two in Photoshop?
Theoretically, you could also remove the water from one image and replace with colour corrected water from the other image in P'shop, too.